# pyspark : How to explode a column of string type into rows and columns of a spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode, pyspark

I am working with spark 2.3 . I have a spark data frame which is of the following format

```
| person_id | person_attributes
____________________________________________________________________________
| id_1    "department=Sales__title=Sales_executive__level=junior"
| id_2    "department=Engineering__title=Software Engineer__level=entry-level"
```

and so on.

The person_attributes column is of the type `string`

How can I explode this frame to get a data frame of the type as follows without the `level` attribute_key

```
| person_id | attribute_key| attribute_value
____________________________________________________________________________
| id_1        department       Sales
| id_1        title            Sales_executive
| id_2        department       Engineering
| id_2        title            Software Engineer
```

This is a big distributed data frame so , converting to pandas or caching is not an option

Comment: You would have to manually parse your string into a map, and then you can use `explode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


 df
  .withColumn("attributes_splitted",  split(col("person_attributes"), "__")) // Split by delimiter `__`
  .withColumn("exploded", explode(col("attributes_splitted"))) // explode the splitted column
  .withColumn("temp", split(col("exploded"), "=")) // again split based on delimiter `=`
  .withColumn("attribute_key", col("temp").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("attribute_value", col("temp").getItem(1))
  .drop("attributes_splitted", "exploded", "temp", "person_attributes")
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked. It also helped me understand breakdown the problem into multiple steps and spark code each and every step

Answer (score 2):

Try this for **`Spark2.3`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("arr", F.split("person_attributes",'\=|__'))\
  .withColumn("map", F.create_map(F.lit('department'),F.col("arr")[1]\
                                  ,F.lit('title'),F.col("arr")[3]))\
  .select("person_id", F.explode("map").alias("attribute_key","attribute_value"))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
#|person_id|attribute_key|attribute_value  |
#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
#|id_1     |department   |Sales            |
#|id_1     |title        |Sales_executive  |
#|id_2     |department   |Engineering      |
#|id_2     |title        |Software Engineer|
#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Try this for **`Spark2.4+`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("arr", F.split("person_attributes",'\=|__'))\
  .withColumn("map", F.map_from_arrays(F.expr("""filter(arr,(x,i)->i%2=0)""")\
                                       ,F.expr("""filter(arr,(x,i)->i%2!=0)""")))\
  .select("person_id", F.explode("map").alias("attribute_key","attribute_value")).filter("""attribute_key!='level'""")\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
#|person_id|attribute_key|attribute_value  |
#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
#|id_1     |department   |Sales            |
#|id_1     |title        |Sales_executive  |
#|id_2     |department   |Engineering      |
#|id_2     |title        |Software Engineer|
#+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```